# Using jQuery .ajax, but popup window still asks for login/password

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I am trying to use .ajax to test a login page we have on an internal app (basic auth) and view the http status code. However, the modal window still pops up prompting for login credentials. Why is this? I am trying to get this to take place behind the scene.

Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      $.ajax({
          url:"./testurl.aspx",
          type: "POST",
          data:{
                username: "Test",
                password: "Password"
          },
          complete: function(xhr){
                alert(xhr.status);
          }
      });
 });
```

But still I get this:

[image]

And then of course the alert(xhr.status) will display, but I need this to without manually entering the username/pw.

Comment: Doesn't basic auth happen before any data is downloaded from the server for the requested resource?  Also, doesn't basic auth happen on every request whether it is a POST or a GET?  The test AJAX you have seems to be targetted at a forms based application.  You'd need to change the actual headers going to the server if you want basic auth to work.  (going off of memory here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is either passed as an HTTP header or in the URL, not in the POST body.

Example putting it in the URL:

```
 $.ajax({
      url:"//Test:Password@" + location.host + "/path/to/testurl.aspx",
      type: "POST",
      complete: function(xhr){
            alert(xhr.status);
      }
  });
```

You can also use the ajax method's [headers](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) property to try and add the header, but that requires Base64 encoding the password.